# Check Cell Style in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has a number of cells styled "Good" and "Bad" From the home tab.  I would like my VBA program to check if a cell is formatted as "Good" or "Bad".  I can't find any answers on here about the style of a cell.  I can tell you what I have tried and found it not working:

if Range("f2").style = "good" then
do stuff
end if

Excel 2010
Thanks for any help

Comment: That doesn't work? What does the error show, if there is one? What happens if you step through the VB script and it gets to that line? (use `F8` to step through).  Check the capitalization in "Good" and "Bad" to match what the style actually has (caps or no caps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I used the "Record Macro" to record me changing these this is the code generated :

```
Range("I6").Select
Selection.Style = "Bad"
Range("I9").Select
Selection.Style = "Good"
```

I conclude that you need to use an upper case "G" ie  "Good"  not "good"

Answer (score 0):

To cover options something like

```
Sub TellMe()
Select Case [f2].Style
    Case "Good"
    Debug.Print "style = Good"
    Case "Bad"
    Debug.Print "style = Bad"
    Case Else
    Debug.Print [f2].Style
End Select
End Sub
```